# Issue with Any/All support in WCF Data Service V5

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

I started using this but Any and All was not working with ReflectionProvider on Linq To SQl. and is failig with following error. Any pointers in how to fix this.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. —> System.Data.Services
 .Client.DataServiceClientException: **An error occurred while processing this request.Argument type
 s do not matchSystem.ArgumentException at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Condition(Expression test**, Expressio
 n ifTrue, Expression ifFalse)
```

Comment: Any expert please. The same works with EF provider in my sample app.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem while using WCF Data Services V5 with NHibernate (which use Re-linq as QueryProvider). I have found that different expressions are generated depending if I run the following LINQ query directly against the NHibernate session or against the Data services client:

```
.Where(x => x.Staff.Any(y => y.FirstName == "Bill"))
```

If I query it against the session it generates the following expression:

```
{value(NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[WcfDataServicesTest.Entities.Store]).Where(x => x.Staff.Any(y =    > (y.FirstName == "Bill")))}
```

But when I query the client I get the following:

```
{value(NHibernate.Linq.NhQueryable`1[WcfDataServicesTest.Entities.Store]).Where(it => IIF((it.Staff == null), Empty(), it.Staff).Any(p => (p.FirstName == "Bill")))}
```

Notice the extra conditional expression (IIF...)?

I don't know the reason yet, but I've found a half decent workaround to use until I do:

http://abilityforge.com/?p=18

EDIT:
Here is a detailed explanation of what seems to be the problem (and a better solution to it): http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/08/how-odata-quirk-killed-nuget-server.html